# Check that object is not instance of any class in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, object, typechecking

I have a function which takes objects and proxies them.

I do not want it to proxy classes, and I'd like to assert that with the argument type.

How can I do this?

---

```
type NonClassObject = ???;
export function createObjectProxy(obj: NonClassObject) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {});
}

const foo: NonClassObject = {};
const bar: NonClassObject = {} as HTMLElement; // this should be a type error
```

---

There doesn't seem to be much to distinguish the two except for the typeof the constructor.  I'm not sure if there's a way to say `Exact<tyepof OBJ.constructor, Object>`... but I'm looking into Utility types now.

[image]
[image]

---

On to something:
[image]

---

Dead end: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841

Comment: The compiler can't know this because, to it, the type of a class instance is indistinguishable from the type of a non-instance whose properties are the right types; the type system is structural.  So `class Foo {x = 1}; const f: Foo = {x: 100}; const g: Foo = new Foo();` will compile, and nothing in TS will distinguish between `f` and `g`.  You'll have to write a user-defined type guard or the like.  Meaning: build a runtime test and then give the test some types to help the compiler.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG9oA9oF5oEZoF8BuAWAChh4A7CAF2gDMAuORLFdZnABi4JPKq1oAc2YIk2SgFMA7i3gAKAJT8aATwAOU6ADkqAYXBQA8gCMAVlOB1s8C1boAydgH0XlA0YhnL15jQAnAFdtIjJ6IMprAEsqaGiIPUpDSG97awU0ZjBKNSVmDATdT1SfBxQyaCroAKkaIIDKdGgAQkxJIJAQaEdndS14emb27AAiO18aUZ7nNAA6CmpAoOt4AKx26DLrfnxwyJi4qhA1JIhM5iSUk3SaJQrSauhFiHgQKTmQeGFMlTI90jHU6CBT0FTQAD0EOgUgCATWABpoIgNBAkQBJaDSKQAE2gNCQwAAFlYANYMaIBWhkaJDBQJK5ebY0UFKe7ISrVIFnVmESHQ+CksBqLHwGRI5BZXA8AEA2nQemJEo3SYKYRs9hQ6A4+BSGAeOjBSicqrckHq3ZkMhAA); if it works for you I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open issue about making the constructor type more defined (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) but it's 4 years old and not seeming to get anywhere.

As a stopgap solution, I've just started adding `{ _noMyProjectProxy: true }` to all my classes, and listing out anything I don't have access to.  It looks like this:

```
type NonClassObject<TYPE> = 
  TYPE extends HTMLElement ? never :
  TYPE extends Event ? never :
  TYPE extends OtherClass ? never :
  TYPE extends { _noMyProjectProxy: any } ? never : 
  TYPE;

export function createObjectProxy<TYPE extends object>(obj: NonClassObject<TYPE>) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {});
}
```

It's not pretty or elegant, but it works when nothing else did.